# Execute git command in hook post-commit

Tags: git, shell, command, hook, post-commit

I have a post-commit hook. I would like to count the commit number every time I commit on my repo. I wrote :

```
#!/bin/sh
commit_number=$(git shortlog | grep -E '^[ ]+\w+' | wc -l)
echo "$commit_number"
```

Every new commit, terminal is printing 0 ... I don't why. If I launch this command after my commit inside my terminal I have the right count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like :

```
cd ..
commit_number=$(env -i git shortlog | grep -E '^[ ]+\w+' | wc -l)
echo "$commit_number"
```

Comment: thx ! I made it with a git rev-list. why shortlog doesn't the same way ?